# Bug with touch movement in a game

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a 2d platfrom game for android and I'm having some trouble with the touch events.
this is my code:

```
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent e, int scaledX, int scaledY) {
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            tempObject = object.get(i);
            if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player) {
                if (moveRight.contains(scaledX, scaledY)) {
                    Log.d("PlayState", "Move button is pressed!");
                    tempObject.setMovingRight(true);

                } else {
                    tempObject.setMovingRight(false);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        for (int i = 0; i < object.size(); i++) {
            tempObject = object.get(i);
            if (tempObject.getId() == ObjectId.Player) {
                if (moveRight.contains(scaledX, scaledY)) {
                    Log.d("PlayState", "Move button is released!");
                    tempObject.setMovingRight(false);

                }
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I touch the rectangle and release inside the rectangle it works great. The problem is that if I touch the rectangle and move my finger somewhere else while touching, the character keeps on moving. My question is how can I program it so "movingRight" will only be true while the touch is happening inside the rectangle.
Thanks !! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can `setMovingRight(false)` when `e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE`.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html) you can find a list of all the possible `MotionEvents`.

The easiest way will be to change this statement `if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)` to `if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE)`

This will work only if the `View` that you've attached the `onTouchEvent(...)` to is not bigger then the player's rectangle. If the `View` is bigger you can try changing

`if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)`
to
`if (e.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN || e.getAction() == MotionEvent.MOVE )`